# warning when overloading operator << for a class within a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, overloading

I get a warning (it works though) when overloading `<<` for a class `Rectangle` in namespace `Shape`. Note that I generated the overload with Clion but still got a warning.

**Rectangle.h**

```
#include <ostream>

namespace Shape {

    class Rectangle {
    public:
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);
    };
}
```

**Rectangle.cpp**

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

using namespace Shape;

std::ostream& Shape::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle) {
    os << "rectangle";
    return os;
}
```

Warning :

```
warning: 'std::ostream& Shape::operator<<(std::ostream&, const Shape::Rectangle&)' has not been declared within Shape
 std::ostream& Shape::operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle) {
               ^~~~~

note: only here as a friend
         friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);
                              ^~~~~~~~
```

How to do it properly so that I don't have a warning?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove `Shape::`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle) {
    os << "rectangle";
    return os;
}
```

Edit: You'd also have to encapsulate your overloaded function definition in `namespace Shape {...}`.

---

Alternatively, you could declare `operator<<()` within `namespace Shape`, but outside `Rectangle`:

```
namespace Shape {

    class Rectangle {
    public:
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);
    };

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i could not guess this!!

Comment: If you do that, then this `operator<<` won't be a friend of `Rectangle`. It'll be an unrelated `operator<<` that is a member of the global namespace. The friend declared within `Rectangle` is, in fact, a member of the `Shape` namespace.

Comment: it worked but it generated an error if I call a function of Rectangle, like this `cout << rectangle.getLength()` , the error is `error: prototype for 'double Shape::Rectangle::getLength() const' does not match any in class 'Shape::Rectangle'`

Comment: @Brian yes exactly, but then how do i not get a warning?

Comment: Add `namespace Shape {` ... `}` around the function.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for pointing out my error; I've gotten rid of the incorrect portion of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

You have to define the overload method within the namespace, not in the class.

```
#include <ostream>

    namespace Shape {

        class Rectangle {
        };
        std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);
    }
```

NOT this way :

```
#include <ostream>

    namespace Shape {

        class Rectangle {
        public:
            friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Rectangle &rectangle);
        };
    }
```